# How do I import db and User in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to follow the [quickstart guide](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/), however I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yourapplication'
```

Comment: You understand that without any context, we cannot provide any help. :/

Comment: Sorry about that. I am using ```from yourapplication import db, User``` . I then realized that 'yourapplication' might be contextual so I used ```from app import db, User``` since the app I'm creating is an ```app.py``` and I got the error ```ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'app' ``` which makes sense because I don't have those in my app so I'm kinda lost @IMCoins

Comment: Where are you using the command `from app import db` ? From your script ?

Comment: Tried both in script and terminal @IMCoins

Comment: It says you must do it in your terminal. Though, you need to be in the curent directory of the application. So, open a terminal, do `cd path/to/your/application`, and then, execute a Python interpreter using `python` / `python3.x`, and do `from app import db` (if your file is properly named `app.py`)